Printing the date of the first unmasked image in an image collection
I have applied two masks to the Sentinel-1 Image Collection. I have masked all MYI images, as well as those whose backscatter change (vs. the backscatter mean) is lower than a certain threshold. Let's call the masked Image Collection collection. I would like to print the date of the first image which is unmasked, but running
print(collection.first().date()) simply prints the date of the first image in the original collection.
How can I print the date of the first unmasked image?

If you're masking individual pixels (using updateMask) then you'll have to do some kind of reduction (probably reduceRegion) on each image to see if there are any unmasked pixels left.  You can map over the collection to do that, saving the result on each image, then filter for count > 0.  Something like:
var filtered = collection.map(function(img) {
    var result = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.count(), roi, scale)
    return img.set(result)
}).filter("count > 0")

